# blank notification appeared in top bar. How can I delete?

Tags: release-loki, notifications, wingpanel

[image: See that blank notification and missing menu?]

I think this is from a recent install of DesktopNova (from App Center), which I have since deleted, but that notification is still there, even after restart. I checked the startup applications, but couldn't see anything out of the ordinary.
How can I find out what application is putting that blank tray icon up there and/or how do i get rid of it?

THANKS!!!

Comment: Have you installed Dropbox?

Comment: No. I haven't installed it at all on this machine.

Comment: I also killed indicator-application-service and it got rid of everything but volume, network bluetooth, battery, notifications, shutdown AND that same blank indicator.
Doesn't that indicate that it's a system process?